# Windows server 2016 does not accept incoming WebSocket connections

Tags: windows-server-2016, websocket

I have started a websocket server with nodejs on my windows server 2016. The nodejs application started listening on port 1337 and I can initiate websocket connection to my localhost:1337 from browser side.

But when I try to initiate a connection on internet outside of the server, it doesn't establish and says:

> failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

** Please consider that I have added port 1337 to my firewall inbound as a rule and I can access to the port by telnet **